# Error when trying to use an image handler in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, blob, httphandler

I've taken the following code from a guide so as to test it, and am experiencing an error saying that `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

**Please note that this is NOT my code, and thus this problem is related to deciphering it.**

```
   public class ProductImageHandler : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            Int32 id;
            if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
                id = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request.QueryString["id"]);
            else
                throw new ArgumentException("No parameter specified");

            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            Stream strm = GetFromDB(id);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);

            while (byteSeq > 0)
            {
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
                byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
            }
            //context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
        }

        public Stream GetFromDB(int id)
        {
            string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn);
            string sql = "SELECT Image FROM Products WHERE ID = @ID";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
            connection.Open();
            object img = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            try
            {
                return new MemoryStream((byte[])img);
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
```

The error occurs in the following line:

`int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);`

Does anyone have any idea as to what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the only member access on the line itself is on `strm`, so I would assume it is a `null` reference.

Check what `GetFromDB` returns for the specific query. I assume it will return a `null` if the `id` is not found.

```
Stream strm = GetFromDB(id);
```

To resolve this, either:

- Update `GetFromDB` to not return a `null`
- Check the passed in `id` to ensure it is valid
- Check that `strm` is not `null` before using it

Comment: Thanks! This was indeed the problem

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because `GetFromDB` returns null. You shouldn't return null when you catch an exception in `GetFromDB`, or if you do, you should test that the return value is not null. Try not to catch the exception, this will show you what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Quite obviously, this line returns null:

```
Stream strm = GetFromDB(id);
```

Check if that method contains the correct implementation and if the supplied id exists.

Answer (score 0):

Your GetFromDB method returns null when an exception is thrown (ick, by the way)...so I'd suggest stepping through it to find out why.

Answer (score 0):

If you put  object img = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); line inside the try block you can modify the catch to catch an actual exception object instead of just returning null.